# How to store description in jpeg image?

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, exif, graphicsmagick

I whant to save image description to jpeg file itself without any external databases or files. I didn't find andy EXIF field for that. Idealy, I want to set description it by imagemagic or same crossplatform tool. What is proper field for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jhead` to set a comment like this:

```
jhead -cl "Some funky comment" a.jpg
Modified: a.jpg
```

Then read it back, also with `jhead`

```
jhead a.jpg
File name    : a.jpg
File size    : 787267 bytes
File date    : 2012:02:03 21:02:15
Resolution   : 3492 x 2286
JPEG Quality : 86
Comment      : Some funky comment   <--- HERE IT IS
```

then check it is visible with ImageMagick's `identify` too:

```
identify -verbose a.jpg 

Image: a.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  ...
  ...
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 86
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    comment: Some funky comment              <--- HERE IT IS
    date:create: 2015-01-19T13:47:43+00:00
    date:modify: 2012-02-03T21:02:15+00:00
```

You can equally set a comment with ImageMagick's `mogrify`

```
mogrify -comment "Freddy Frog" a.jpg
```

and check with `jhead`

```
jhead a.jpg
File name    : a.jpg
File size    : 880639 bytes
File date    : 2015:01:19 13:52:51
Resolution   : 3492 x 2286
JPEG Quality : 86
Comment      : Freddy Frog   <--- HERE IT IS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/download.html) command line on most platforms.
You can get all available fields with :

```
exiv2 -pv img.jpg
```

You might use `Exif.Photo.UserComment`
for example as a field for description but you can see there a lot of other fields available on the samples [here](http://www.exiv2.org/sample.html) 
and then use `exiv2 -M` to change some metadata in your image

Answer (score 0):

I think the Exif tag you are looking for is "ImageDescription".  You can write this with [ExifTool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) using this command:

```
exiftool -imagedescription="Some Description" file.jpg
```

This is a cross-platform tool as you requested, and can read/write many different file and metadata formats.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JPEG comment tag you could use for this. You could write a simple program to insert comments. The format of the tag is simple and you can insert it into the stream after the header markers.